# Get n-th child Element with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

For example a web site has a code like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        first
    </div>
    <div>
        second
    </div>
    <div>
        third
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to get the "second" div text with "Jsoup" and it has no attribute or class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are few ways to do it.

For instance we could use `select` method which returns `Elements` with all specified elements. Since `Elements extends ArrayList<Element>` it inherits all of `ArrayList` public methods. This means we can use `get(index)` method to select specific child (starting from 0)

```
 String html = 
        "<div>\n" +
        "    <div>\n" +
        "        first\n" +
        "    </div>\n" +
        "    <div>\n" +
        "        second\n" +
        "    </div>\n" +
        "    <div>\n" +
        "        third\n" +
        "    </div>\n" +
        "</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements select = doc.select("div > div");
System.out.println(select.get(1));
```

Output:

```
<div>
  second 
</div>
```

Another way could be using `:eq(n)` in CSS selector (from [official Jsoup tutorial](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax))

> `:eq(n)`: find elements whose sibling index is equal to `n`; e.g. form `input:eq(1)`

like

```
System.out.println(doc.select("div > div:eq(1)"));
```